# What is best way to meet previous employer for just having good relation?

Tags: professionalism, employer-relations, employer

I worked at X company for 5 in Dubai and then moved back to my home country. 
I got an offer from a different company, and decided to moved back.

I am in Dubai now and wanted to meet my previous employer just for maintaining the good relationshig, and nothing else.

The employer was very good to me and  I am thinking I should purchase a gift for the employer or the agency as a "thank you" gift, to just make him happy.

I need your suggestion on how to approach him, and to keep up good relations. Because of lack of knowledge I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Is gift giving a common/encouraged part of the culture in Dubai when meeting with friends/acquaintances/business associates?

Comment: @dfundako it is not

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Since he is CEO so I don't think he will get sometime for me. As you know such kind of people usually very busy and they have to a lot of stuff like meetings etc

Answer (score 6):

The idea of a gift sounds a bit strange to me.. getting in touch and saying that you are in the country and asking if they want to meet up for lunch/coffee or whatever for a chat sounds fine to me.

Comment: I say thanks for your suggestion but they people usually very busy and I am not sure he will ...?

Comment: @ScriptLover but they will likely still appreciate the gesture (which gets most of your goals met no?) and if they were too busy to meet up for coffee they are probably too busy to meet you for a "gift", and if you aren't going to meet them it's something you could have done from any country

Comment: Let me tell you the real reason which is I am too shy I can't say. I accept this idea will be fine but if he say yes then I can't go for a coffee with him.